# Paytm integration with angular and spring boot

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, payment-gateway, paytm

I am trying to integrate Paytm payment gateway with spring-boot as backend an angular as front end. I am able to hit the controller but not able to redirect url to paytm to proceed with payment. Currently I can see Paytm UI load for a moment in the router outlet div and then it disappear immediately. I think there is some issue with angular http call or router outlet. Not sure where is the mistake. Any help is much appreciated.

My spring boot controller code:

```
@Log4j2
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/booking")
public class BookingController {

    @Autowired
    private PaytmDetails paytmDetails;

    @Value("${paytm.mobile}")
    private String paytmMobile;
    @Value("${paytm.email}")
    private String paytmEmail;

    @PostMapping(value = "/make-payment")
    public ModelAndView getPaymentRedirect(@RequestParam String orderId, @RequestParam String txnAmount, @RequestParam String customerId) throws Exception {
        log.info("1=========");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:" + paytmDetails.getPaytmUrl());
        log.info("2=========");
        TreeMap<String, String> parameters = new TreeMap<>();
        paytmDetails.getDetails().forEach((k, v) -> parameters.put(k, v));
        parameters.put("MOBILE_NO", paytmMobile);
        parameters.put("EMAIL", paytmEmail);
        parameters.put("ORDER_ID", orderId);
        parameters.put("TXN_AMOUNT", txnAmount);
        parameters.put("CUST_ID", customerId);
        String checkSum = getCheckSum(parameters);
        parameters.put("CHECKSUMHASH", checkSum);
        log.info("3=========");
        modelAndView.addAllObjects(parameters);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/payment-response")
    public ModelAndView getPaymentResponseRedirect(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:http://localhost:8080/#/payment");//my angular payment response landing url
        Map<String, String[]> mapData = request.getParameterMap();
        TreeMap<String, String> parameters = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        String paytmChecksum = "";
        for (Entry<String, String[]> requestParamsEntry : mapData.entrySet()) {
            if ("CHECKSUMHASH".equalsIgnoreCase(requestParamsEntry.getKey())) {
                paytmChecksum = requestParamsEntry.getValue()[0];
            } else {
                parameters.put(requestParamsEntry.getKey(), requestParamsEntry.getValue()[0]);
            }
        }
        String result;
        boolean isValideChecksum = false;
        try {
            isValideChecksum = validateCheckSum(parameters, paytmChecksum);
            if (isValideChecksum && parameters.containsKey("RESPCODE")) {
                if (parameters.get("RESPCODE").equals("01")) {
                    result = "Payment Successful";
                } else {
                    result = "Payment Failed";
                }
            } else {
                result = "Checksum mismatched";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = e.toString();
        }
        modelAndView.addObject("result", result);
        parameters.remove("CHECKSUMHASH");
        modelAndView.addObject("parameters", parameters);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    private boolean validateCheckSum(TreeMap<String, String> parameters, String paytmChecksum) throws Exception {
        return PaytmChecksum.verifySignature(parameters, paytmDetails.getMerchantKey(), paytmChecksum);
    }

    private String getCheckSum(TreeMap<String, String> parameters) throws Exception {
        return PaytmChecksum.generateSignature(parameters, paytmDetails.getMerchantKey());
    }

}
```

My PaytmPojo

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("paytm.payment.sandbox")
public class PaytmDetails {

    private String merchantId;
    private String merchantKey;
    private String channelId;
    private String website;
    private String industryTypeId;
    private String paytmUrl;
    private String callbackUrl;
    private Map<String, String> details;

}
```

Resource file:

```
paytm.payment.sandbox.merchantId=<test valid paytm MID>
paytm.payment.sandbox.merchantKey=<tes valid paytm MK>
paytm.payment.sandbox.channelId=WEB
paytm.payment.sandbox.industryTypeId=Retail
paytm.payment.sandbox.website=WEBSTAGING
paytm.payment.sandbox.paytmUrl=https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/order/process
paytm.payment.sandbox.callbackUrl=http://localhost:8080/user/booking/payment-response
paytm.payment.sandbox.details.MID=${paytm.payment.sandbox.merchantId}
paytm.payment.sandbox.details.CHANNEL_ID=${paytm.payment.sandbox.channelId}
paytm.payment.sandbox.details.INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID=${paytm.payment.sandbox.industryTypeId}
paytm.payment.sandbox.details.WEBSITE=${paytm.payment.sandbox.website}
paytm.payment.sandbox.details.CALLBACK_URL=${paytm.payment.sandbox.callbackUrl}
paytm.mobile=<paytm login mobile>
paytm.email=<paytm login email>
```

Angular component class method:

```
bookProduct() {
    this.availabilityService.bookAvailabileProduct(this.orderId, this.txnAmount, this.customerId).subscribe(
    res => {
      //nothing
    }, err => {
      this.availabilityErrorMsg = "Backend Error!";
      this.availabilityError = true;
    }
  );
}
```

Angular service class method:

```
public bookAvailabileProduct(orderId:any, txnAmount:any, customerId:any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post("/booking//make-payment?orderId="+orderId+"&txnAmount="+txnAmount+"&customerId="+customerId, null);
}
```

Current error in HTML console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/order/process?CALLBACK_URL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fuser%2Fbooking%2Fpayment-response&CHANNEL_ID=WEB&CHECKSUMHASH=D9DRS%2Bn0TfhKMW%2FY6brrKt5%2BbcTtyuUPlWmQ%2BUNIKr7klkSw%3D&CUST_ID=62f5c339ffc4f516cfeda&EMAIL=shashiranjan.sit%40gmail.com&INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID=Retail&MID=Mo144&MOBILE_NO=9538320000&ORDER_ID=6314be8cff&TXN_AMOUNT=1.0&WEBSITE=WEBSTAGING' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/user/booking/make-payment') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending a model view redirect, you can just pass the URL to your client, and at the client, you can use "window.location.replace()"

Comment: Before making any call to Paytm I wanted to get some details from my app and save some data. There are some checks which I have to perform before making payment call.

Comment: How to manage those checksum magic in client side?

Comment: You can think of generating checksum, validating checksum and callback at the spring boot side, and then the rest of all logic could be on the client side itself.

Comment: I am using `window.location.replace("https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/order/process?"+paymentQuery);` but it seems that Paytm web is not able to read the parameters. Complaining about MID and ORDER_ID as mandatory, although I am passing it.

Comment: The problem is: with window.replace(), the call is becoming GET call not POST call. Somehow it needs to be POST call.

Answer (score 0):

[Paytm flow (happy day)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dlB4.png)

We used "JS Checkout" feature of the paytm earlier with modification as above, to support and restrict secret key maintenance at our server.

Comment: Paytm dev community replied me a link https://github.com/paytm/paytm-blink-checkout-angular , I am trying it now.